# Reading output of shell command in awk script

Tags: shell, awk

I have a text file with a list ip addresses and other information.

I am using an awk script to process this list and output various computations. I want to call `dig -x` from inside the awk script and use the returned value.

I have tried

```
hostname = system("dig +short -x" ip_address);
```

but what occurs is -

1. the call to dig prints a line to the shell
2. hostname remains null

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured it out, but please feel free to add better answers

```
cmd = "dig +short -x " ;
cmd ip_address | getline hostname;
close(cmd)
```

Then I can use the hostname anywhere in the script.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. You will probably want to do `close(cmd)` afterwards.

Comment: Yes thanks, found out about that after this posting, will close the question in 2 days(superuser requirement)